# how does laravel with() method work for RedirectResponse

Tags: php, laravel

really this question makes me crazy. now I want to ask about laravel `with()` which is used for `RedirectResponse`.i searched a lot and research but I am not able to get success and proper satisfaction.so here is the main question.
we can use `with()` for `RedirectResponse` like this

```
return view('name')->with(['demo'=>$demo]);
```

Or

```
return view('name')->with('demo',$demo);
```

given above methods are understandable for me
the problem is here.we can also use like this.

```
return view('name')->withDemo($demo);
```

so i am not able to understand logic behind `withDemo()` because `withDemo()` is not defined any where.i searched in laravel about `with()`. i found some info about that here is the path

```
vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.php
```

I found something like this

```
public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        if (static::hasMacro($method)) {
            return $this->macroCall($method, $parameters);
        }

        if (Str::startsWith($method, 'with')) {
            return $this->with(Str::snake(substr($method, 4)), $parameters[0]);
        }

        throw new BadMethodCallException(
            "Method [$method] does not exist on Redirect."
        );
    }
```

please anyone can explain the logic behind dynamic defined method like `withDemo()`
it could be duplicate question sorry for that but I searched a lot. I did not find related to this topic.

Comment: ->withDemo($demo) , you get that value in session in redirect page

Comment: no i am not asking about session and redirect please read whole question

Comment: okay why you need to define  method ?

Comment: This is happening with magic function __call in PHP. Read this http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same sort of magic does appear on the RedirectResponse, but you're probably interested in this code that on the `Illuminate\View\View`:

```
/**
 * Dynamically bind parameters to the view.
 *
 * @param  string  $method
 * @param  array   $parameters
 * @return \Illuminate\View\View
 *
 * @throws \BadMethodCallException
 */
public function __call($method, $parameters)
{
    if (static::hasMacro($method)) {
        return $this->macroCall($method, $parameters);
    }

    if (! Str::startsWith($method, 'with')) {
        throw new BadMethodCallException(sprintf(
            'Method %s::%s does not exist.', static::class, $method
        ));
    }

    return $this->with(Str::camel(substr($method, 4)), $parameters[0]);
}
```

Like @abrar pointed out this is using PHP's magic methods. When you call a method that does not exist on an object PHP will instead call `__call()` passing in the method name and the arguments.

You can see here that Laravel will first check to see if a macro exists and use that if it does. Otherwise it confirms that the method name starts with `with` and then simply passes it on to the `with()` method as it would if you called it directly.

Answer (score 1):

`__call($method, $parameters)` gets called whenever you try to call an undefined method.

When you call `withDemo($demo)` the interpreter jumps into `__call($method, $parameters)`

```
$method = 'withDemo';
$parameters = [$demo];
```

'with' gets stripped in the `substr` function call and it get's snake cased.

The 'real' call with variable names 'stripped' looks something like this:

```
return $this->with('demo', $parameters[0]); // $parameters[0] -> $demo
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easier way to write function and parameter together

eg. `with('key1', 'value1')` OR `withKey1('value1')`

eg. `where('mycolumn', 'value')` OR `whereMycolumn('value')`